# request.getParamaterValues() not supporting UTF-8 while request.getParameter() does

Tags: java, servlets, encoding, utf-8

An HTML UTF-8 page (`<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>`) is using a form with single- and multi-valued fields.

A single valued field sending special characters (such as ä ö ü) is working fine by using `request.getParameter(NAME)`.

However if you use a multi-valued field and try to receive the values via `request.getParameterValues(MULTI)` then the special characters are not decoded correctly.

Is this a bug in the servlet spec, specifically in the `getParameterValues()` method or am I missing something?

I discovered this issue in a web application running on Tomcat 5 and Java SE 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I got a working solution (workaround). However, I would still be interested why the straight forward approach does not work...

**Working solution:**

```
String[] strings = request.getParameterValues("multi");
if (strings != null) {
    if (response.getCharacterEncoding().equals("ISO-8859-1")) {
        for (int i=0; i<strings.length; i++) {
            strings[i] = URLDecoder.decode(new String(strings[i].getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
        }
    }
    for (String s: strings) {
        // do whatever you want with correctly encoded special characters
    }
}
```

**Code that does not work (but should?):**

```
String[] strings = request.getParameterValues("multi");
if (strings != null) {
    for (String s: strings) {
        // special characters in variable s do not appear correctly
    }
}
```